# Merge cells in a table

Tags: tables

Do you know how can I merge 4 cells from two different collums and two rows? Can I use both multicol and multi row?
Thanks

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Population to serve}\multirow{2}{6cm}{Population to serve}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid your writeup isn't very clear. Please elaborate on what you mean by "merging 4 cells".

Comment: For example, merge cells A1+A2+B1+B2

Comment: @CarolinaCastro Have a look at the `tabularray` package. It make merging cells very easy.

Comment: It'd be clearer if you could include an image of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @CarolinaCastro  please upvote and accept with a green tick if the answer met your expectations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & c \\
\hline
d & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2.2}{*}{efhi}}  \\
\cline{1-1}
g & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you that's it. But what do you mean with \multirow{2.2}? 2 columns+2 lines?

Comment: @CarolinaCastro - The first argument of `\multirow` needn't be an integer. Since I've also set `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`, it seemed appropriate to use 2.2 instead of just 2.

Answer (score 4):

With package `NiceMatrix / NiceTabular`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \begin{NiceTabular}[]{cccc}  
            \CodeBefore
            \rectanglecolor{blue!20}{2-1}{3-2}
            \Body
            \toprule  
            Column1&Column2&Column3&Column4\\ \midrule
            \Block{2-2}{R2*C2}& &Row2  &Row2   \\ 
                                        &&Row3&Row3\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular} 
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```